# Understanding matter.js code for Box: this, push and pop

Tags: javascript, this, matter.js

I am new to JavaScript and having a difficult time understanding the following code snippet intuitively.  It is code used to make a box in some physics engine (matter.js)

```
function Box(x, y, w, h){
    this.body = Bodies.rectangle(x,y,80,80);
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    World.add(world, this.body)

    this.show = function(){
        var pos = this.body.position;
        var angle = this.body.angle;

        push();
        translate(pos.x, pos.y);
        rect(0,0,this.w,this.h);

        pop();
    }
}
box1 = new Box(200,100,50,50)
function draw() {
background(51);
box1.show();

}
```

My questions are this:

- why not just use w or h, why assign "this.w" to w and "this.h" to h
- i am confused by the push(). why is nothing in the parenthesis? what is it adding by default?
- same thing with the pop().  What is it removing?

Comment: Share the implementations of `push()` and `pop()`.

Comment: `push` and `pop` are often used by graphics libraries to control the mutations of what's being drawn. The `push` pushes a new transformation to be applied, the `translate` transformation happens, the `rect` is drawn with the current transformations, then `pop` pops (removes) the current transformation so it doesn't effect anything else being drawn.

Comment: Since `show()` is not on the `prototype`, initializing `w` and `h` on the instance offers no benefit here (other than making them mutable outside the constructor). Typically member methods should be defined like `Box.prototype.show = function () { ... };` outside the constructor, in which case initializing `w` and `h` on the instance _would_ be necessary.

Comment: this keyword refers to the object it belongs to. Here we cant use w or h because they are just local variables of a function Box or we can say they have block level scoping and therefore they cant be used outside that block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why not just use w or h, why assign "this.w" to w and "this.h" to h

this allows the w and h to be properties of the Box. After, if you were to say

```
box1 = new Box(10,10,10,10)
console.log(box1.w, box1.h)
```

you would be able to see and manipulate those properties. Because your rectangle is using these properties to draw itself if you manipulate those properties the drawing of your rectangle will change as well.

> i am confused by the push(). why is nothing in the parenthesis? what is it adding by default?

I believe you're looking at code utilizing the p5.js library. `push()` and `pop()` in p5.js access the draw state. Essentially, `push()` is 'begin drawing' and `pop()` is 'stop drawing'. So, here they access the draw state, draw a rectangle, and then close the draw state.

You can read more on p5's [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push).